# Angular checkbox only binds one way with Firestore doc

Tags: angular, data-binding, google-cloud-firestore, observable

I have a Firestore document with a boolean field that I want to bind to a checkbox. This is what I was doing to bind:

Get the observable in the component:

```
this.doc$ = await this.afs.collection('docs').doc<Doc>(docId).valueChanges()
```

Use the observable in the template:

```
<div *ngIf="doc$ | async as doc;">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="doc.checkValue">
</div>
```

If I update the document on Firestore through the console, the checkbox reflects the current state correctly but when I update the checkbox, the Firestore document does not get updated. I thought this was the preferred method instead of using checked but is that wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it didn't update directly from the template using snapshotChanges() instead of valueChanges(), I just did an end-run and used the template change event to push an update to Firestore through a function added to the component:

In the template:

```
(change)="onCheckChange(doc)
```

and in the component:

```
onCheckChange(doc: Doc) {
this.afs.collection('docs').doc(doc.docId).update({ checkValue: doc.checkValue })
}
```

I don't think that's the best way to do it, but I'm stuck for the moment and this at least let's me drive on. I'd still really like to know what the proper way to handle this through the template is with AngularFire though. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly there is only `valueChanges()` Observable is implemented.  According to the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#valuechanges) it's:

> valueChanges()
>
> What is it? - Returns an Observable of document data.
> All Snapshot metadata is stripped. This method provides only the data.
>
> Why would you use it? - When you just need the object data. No
> document metadata is attached which makes it simple to render to a
> view.
>
> When would you not use it? - When you need the id of the document to
> use data manipulation methods. This method assumes you either are
> saving the id to the document data or using a "readonly" approach.

You may find in the same documentation as well part about [Manipulating documents](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#manipulating-documents).

So there is listener implemented that updates the checkbox when change appears in database, and now, I guess, there should have been function as well implemented, that will update database when checkbox value changes.

I hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks for the info vitooh. I tried changing valueChanges to snapshotChanges but this still acts the same: Direct changes to the document from the Firestore console show up immediately in the template but changes from the template are not propegated back to Firestore. This is the code I used: ```this.doc$ = this._afs.collection('docs').doc<Doc>(docId).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(a => {return a.payload.data();}))```